# INNER JOIN on ManyToMany JPA not working

Tags: mysql, jpa, inner-join

I am using Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0.GA in Jboss 5.1. But although in my mysql console the query seems to work fine. I get the following error

sqlstate s0022
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'code' not found.

I have two tables one is Station with fields id,code,type and the other is a manyToMany table describing possible combinations

```
+------------+--------+--------+
| ID |       |  type  | code   |
+------------+--------+--------+
|      1     |   AP   |  LAX   |
|      2     |   AP   |  JFK   |
|      3     |   AP   |  LHR   |
|      4     |   AP   |  MAN   |
+------------+--------+--------+

+------------+--------+--------+
| depStationId | destStationId | 
+------------+--------+--------+
|      1     |       2         |
|      1     |       3         |
|      2     |       1         |
|      3     |       1         |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

My Native Query called is

```
select d.code as origin, a.code as destination from DepDest dd 
inner join STATIONS d on dd.depStationId=d.id  and d.type=?1 
inner join STATIONS a on dd.destStationId=a.id and a.type=?2
```

It seems to have something to do with  double left joisn within a query and same column names. I have found this relative but still there is no workaround.

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3988

Can anyone suggest a workaround
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a sub-query?

```
select d.code as origin, a.code as destination
from (
  select dd.destStationId, d.code DepDest dd
  inner join STATIONS d on dd.depStationId=d.id and d.type=?1) d
inner join STATIONS a on d.destStationId=a.id and a.type=?2
```